# Assert response in grails

Tags: testing, grails, http-response-codes

I'm writing a test case for a REST api resource in grails. With the following setup, the test case fails.

```
Map<String, String> headers = ['Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': 'text/plain']
String content = ''
sendRequest '/api/domainName/path', 'GET', headers, content.bytes
assertResponseStatus(200)
```

This results in a **java.lang.AssertionError** error. But with the following setup, this test cases passes.

```
Map<String, String> headers = ['Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': 'text/plain']
String content = ''
sendRequest '/api/domainName/path', 'GET', headers, content.bytes
HttpServletResponse response = getResponse()
assert 200 == response.status
assert 'text/plain' == response.contentType
```

What is the difference between `assertResponseStatus 200` and `assert 200 == getResponse().status`. Why does one pass and the other fail?

Comment: What lib is this?

Comment: @BilalShah, I'm not sure what you mean but this was a snippet from a junit test in grails.